# Parsing nested JSON using Decodable's init(from decoder:)

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable

I'm decoding JSON using Decodable with init(from decoder:) but unable to parse out my nested JSON.

The JSON I'm trying to parse:
The main conflict I believe is parsing the array of edges.
The goal is to get a model I can use with key, value, and namespace.
Would need to use init(from decoder:).

```
{
  "data": {
    "collectionByHandle": {
      "metafields": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "key": "city",
              "value": "Fayetteville ",
              "namespace": "shipping"
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "key": "country",
              "value": "United States",
              "namespace": "shipping"
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "key": "state",
              "value": "AR",
              "namespace": "shipping"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "errors": null
}
```

This technically works but wanting to use init(from decoder: ) and return a model that just has key, value, and namespace without having multiple separate structs/classes.

```
 struct Shipping: Codable {
    let data: DataClass
    let errors: String?
 }

 struct DataClass: Codable {
    let collectionByHandle: CollectionByHandle
 }

 struct CollectionByHandle: Codable {
    let metafields: Metafields
 }

 struct Metafields: Codable {
    let edges: [Edge]
 }

 struct Edge: Codable {
    let node: Node
 }

 struct Node: Codable {
    let key, value, namespace: String
 }
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant code and error messages (all as text).

Comment: updated the post. Thank you for the input